# Pagination from request in Yii2 REST service

Tags: yii2

I'm using Yii2 rest controller that has built in support of pagination.

From docs I can see that the response has some headers that includes useful information about pagination (page size, current page, total pages, total results) but I can't find how to specify pagination through service request from client.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the headers I found that you can specify the following parameters within the request:

```
- page: sets the current page
- per-page: sets the number of results per page
```